# How to get the result of the confirm popup in to a variable in spring MVC?

Tags: javascript, spring, jsp

This is my jsp page

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script>
function getChoice(){
    var k=confirm("Do you want me to overwrite the existing file ?");
    return k;
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:powderblue;color:Tomato">
<center><form method="POST" action="saveagain">    
<h3>${message} </h3>
            <br> <br>
<input type="hidden" name="fname" value="${filename}">
<input type="hidden" name="fcontent" value="${filecontent}"> <br><br>
 <input type="button" value="Overwrite ?" onclick="choice=getChoice()"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit ?"></form></center>
<br>
<br>
<center><b>${m}</b></center>
<br><br>
<center><a href="toupload">Click me to upload a file</a>  <br><br>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

In the above code, i want to get the result of confirm popup in to a variable "choice". How to do that ?

> Modified code :

bean class :

```
package com.fss;

public class Choice {
 private String choice;
private String fname;
private String fcontent;

public String getChoice() {
    return choice;
}

public void setChoice(String choice) {
    this.choice = choice;
}

public String getFname() {
    return fname;
}

public void setFname(String fname) {
    this.fname = fname;
}

public String getFcontent() {
    return fcontent;
}

public void setFcontent(String fcontent) {
    this.fcontent = fcontent;
}


}
```

this is my jsp page :

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function getUserChoice(){
    var k=confirm("Do you want me to overwrite the existing file ?");
    $('#choice').val(k);
    return k;
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center><h3>${message} </h3></center>
            <br>
  <center><form method="POST" action="saveagain">    
    <input type="hidden" name="fname" value="${filename}">
    <input type="hidden" name="fcontent" value="${filecontent}">
    <input type="hidden" name="choice" id="choice"> <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Overwrite ?" onclick="getUserChoice()"/></form></center>         
<center><a href="toupload">Click me to upload a file</a>  </center>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my Controller class:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/saveagain",method = RequestMethod.POST)    
 public ModelAndView fileUploading2(@ModelAttribute("ch") Choice ch) throws IOException{

     String ch1;
     String message="";
     ch1=ch.getChoice();
     System.out.println("popup result "+ch1);
     return new ModelAndView("fileUpload","message",message); 
 }
```

fname and fcontent values are reflecting in controller. why is choice value not reflecting in "ch1" ?

Comment: create a custom popup with  `buttons`  `proceed` and `cancel` then handle click event of buttons.

Comment: The above code is storing the confirm output into `choice` variable.

Comment: @Aditya singh  Yes and choice is a bean variable.

Answer (score 0):

With your approach, you can use javascript in the getChoice() function to put the return value(true/false) as an hidden element value and retrieve on the server side

```
function getChoice() {
    var k=confirm("Do you want me to overwrite the existing file ?");
    $('#hidden_choice').val(k);
}


<!-- HTML element -->
<input type="hidden" name="choice" id="hidden_choice" />
<input id="button_id" type="button" value="Overwrite ?" onclick="getChoice()"/>
```

On the server side, you can use @RequestParam to retrieve the value. Following is the Example code:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/saveagain",method = RequestMethod.POST)  
 public ModelAndView fileUploading2(@RequestParam("choice") Boolean ch) throws IOException {
      // do your thing with choice variable here
      System.out.println("Choice is: " + ch);
}
```

If the boolean value does not work, try with String and convert it to Boolean value manually.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a variable such as `cofirmstatus` in the form.

```
<input type="hidden" name="cofirmstatus" id="cofirmstatus">
```

And set the value as below

```
function getChoice(){
    var k=confirm("Do you want me to overwrite the existing file ?");
    $('#cofirmstatus').val(k);
    return k;
}
```

So, once the form is submitted, this value will be available on the server side

**EDIT:**

I created the JSP as follows. No changes required on server side.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitForm(){
    var k=confirm("Do you want me to overwrite the existing file ?");
    document.myform.choice.value=k;
    document.myform.submit();
}
</script>
</head>
<body style="background-color:powderblue;color:Tomato">
<center><form method="POST" action="saveagain" name="myform">
<h3>${message} </h3>
            <br> <br>
<input type="hidden" name="fname" value="${filename}">
<input type="hidden" name="fcontent" value="${filecontent}"> <br><br>
<input type="hidden" name="choice" id="choice"> <br><br>
 <input type="button" value="Overwrite ?" onclick="javascript:submitForm()"/>
<input type="submit" value="Submit ?"></form></center>
<br>
<br>
<center><b>${m}</b></center>
<br><br>
<center><a href="toupload">Click me to upload a file</a>  <br><br>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Output on server for both the actions:

```
popup result true
popup result false
```

Comment: Is "cofirmstatus" a bean variable ? If not how to get its value in Controller ?

Comment: You can get it using `@RequestParam` on the server side.

Comment: I changed the code like above mentioned. It is now giving syntactically incorrect error. "choice" is my bean variable. Is there any way to get the value of confirm popup into "choice".

Comment: You can get the `cofirmstatus` in the same way as `fname` and `fcontent` on the server side.

Comment: If `choice` is your bean variable, then change your hidden box to `<input type="hidden" name="choice" id="choice">`  and in the function use `$('#choice).val(k);`

Comment: I modified the code.  ch.getChoice() in controller is not printing anything. I am adding the modified code in question. please check it